# Writing is never the same, yet we accept it as the same

Tags: metaphysics

Think about this:

x

When you **Write** it twice physically,

2x will for example, **never** look the same as 2x when you write it again.

It will look **similar, but NEVER the same.**

Yet we accept the same meaning that the 2x's mean the same thing.

Why? Is this just how interpretation works?

Comment: Great question in the field of machine recognition of handwriting, voices, faces, etc. Just how close is close. What does make two things the same? Good question IMO.

Answer (score 4):

What you've articulated is actually Hegel's critique of the law of the excluded middle -- well at least if you unhinge it from the specific question of **writing**. This problem remains regardless of whether it is spoken, written, or somehow otherwise expressed -- even showing the same symbol twice.

Short version: writing A twice means *two* As  -- not **perfectly** identical As.

Longer version: "same" has more than one meaning and we need to be careful what we mean by that. Turns out the law of non-contradictions is at least in part in our heads.

So Yes, we interpret things by recognizing that we are unifying two things under the same category/kind/sortal. And yes, this is part of what we do in interpretation, but it could also be said to just be a feature of consciousness and how we categorize things.

But the undoing of the problem is found in the problem itself. Perfect identity is not really the goal of thinking. Similar -- as in same in kind -- is enough for what we usually want.

Comment: thanks for replying. This response makes good sense. I am a mathematician, so I was wondering about this aspect. Since We interpret x^2 and 2x as having the same meaning of x.So similar looking things having the same meaning in interpretation? It is kind of like identification of laptops. When you see an HP, and a Mac, you notice they are laptops because of the structure. SO: In interpretation we take similar being the same thing?

Comment: similar in *the right respect*. And how we determine that respect varies greatly by philosophical theory.

Comment: So this topic was actually philosophy? The issue with philosophy I have is that if et stuck thinking on it, but in the end all we can do is speculate in philosophy,th ere isn't a definite answer, is there? So is it better to. Accept it as a fact?

Comment: It's not that all we can do is speculate, so much as answers depend on more than just rules of logic. In most contexts, most theories will agree that (a) the law of non-contradiction works for what it's supposed to do and (b) there are circumstances where we need to distinguish supposedly identical cases.

Comment: @Amad27 Outside formal science there is nothing certain. But as everywhere there are better and worse conjectures, and as everywhere one must find out, which is which. But you are right: [Synthetic propositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic–synthetic_distinction) are rarely certain.

Comment: @Amad27 In philosophy there are often definite answers, plural, all of which are incompatible with one another.  The complexity or nature of the subject matter may have to rest on [inductive reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning), or otherwise make it impossible to demonstrate the truth of something empirically, hence there can be no real experts that decide for you, only those that can point you to current/previous thinking on the topic, etc.  You must then decide which line of reasoning looks best to you; philosophical training is supposed to help you do this.

Comment: Sometimes the conclusions generally agree regardless of method, system, or belief. E.g., in ethics, willful killing of an innocent is wrong. In logic, contradictions show an error. In metaphysics, pointless entities are a waste (but here the question is what is pointless)

Comment: Exactly.... This question is pointless because it can't be answered. There is no reason why you interpret identical objects having equal meaning. You just do it.

Comment: @Amad27 - You are not looking very deeply for reasons if "you just do it" is your only answer.  You do intuitively do it, but it is not arbitrary that your intuition is that way, and it is not only intuition that encourages you to do it.

Comment: Surely, there are many reasons why we interpret similar objects to be identical or similar in some respects. At a minimum we do this to manage how much we need to process from the environment. If I cannot recognize two things as apples vs. two pieces of hemlock, life is going to be exceptionally difficult.

Comment: @virmaior, thanks. Then why do we interpret similar objects to have the same meaning, like in algebra?

Comment: @Amad27 That's kind of the point with algebra. To use the same symbol for the same meaning even when it occurs in different places. Often we do this in reasoning as well. I'm lost as to why this is a problem.

Comment: @virmaior, thank you so much . I appreciate every bit of this. The point of math is to have the same variable meaning for similar looking variables, letters, struvtures. Please tell me if this is correct. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: @virmaior, please?

Answer (score 2):

We would like to be able to convey meaning.  Unfortunately, we cannot produce two identical anything--so how do we convey anything?  It's all different!  Fortunately, we don't need to be completely exact: as long as `2x` is more like another *2x* than anything else (e.g. `uu` or *x2*), and we can detect this reliably, we can declare that all 2x'es are equivalent.

You can make this mathematically precise in a wide variety of ways, e.g. by declaring all instances of **2x** members of the 2x equivalence class, and having a rule that unless you specifically call attention to some other feature (perhaps determined by context), any member of the 2x equivalence class should be interpreted as the whole class.  (And then do all your reasoning with that class.)

You could use a Platonic form instead of the equivalence class, or use mathematical clustering to define some group of same-enough things (and then e.g. use the midpoint of the cluster as the canonical one), etc. etc..

(Note: to get off the ground to have any concepts at all, your brain almost certainly does some manner of clustering on its inputs, among other things.)

Comment: thanks for the reply here. I suppose this is one of the most accurate answers; The first line makes sense that "we would like to be able to convey meaning." It is true that we need some communication means, so this is good. So I suppose the answer is: it is just how humans interpret and communicate.

Comment: thank you. I feel this is a great answer. Would you mind helping me a little more? The forms idea is good. So the assumption is identical things mean the same thing? I read on Wiki about the circle being a "perfect circle," which is unachievable. This can be wrong but would you say this is the best way to go about it?

Comment: @Amad27 - The assumption is that if something is close to a known ideal (e.g. circle, the symbols `2x`, etc.), unless you have other information that indicates you should pay attention to the differences, you should treat it as if it were the ideal (a perfect circle, an idealized `2x`).  Once you have done this, it is much easier to convey meaning because you can refer to a symbol that you will see again.  Which way is _best_ depends on what you're trying to do.  Logical or mathematical analysis generally meshes well with ideal forms.

Comment: I suppose this is right, though it_can be false_ can't it? I mean, it is a gamble, but sensibly you should connect it to previous experience and how things look like shouldn't you? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27 - It is of course possible for it to be false, but it's a good bet.  (That is, it's a sound thing to do statistically; it's not merely arbitrary even though it's not completely assured.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I appreciate it very much.So the verdict: Similar things mean the same thing, but this can very well be wrong, but its the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Meanings don't come from cosmic process in the manner of Helium. Meanings are constructed by people.

`2x` is ordinarily the same as `2x` because that's what we ordinarily mean by "is ordinarily the same".

Occasional experiences of philosophical confusion result from a mistake: That meanings have some existence independent of our use of them and a general consensus among us as a language community. Playing along with the confusion requires us to ignore the subtleties of the consensus: The we don't say that the `2x`'s in `2x6x10` and `32xaviar@hotmail.com` are the same in ordinary circumstances. [1]

Take two Wittgenstein and call me in the morning.

[1] We are ordinarily very clear about the contexts in which we would say that they are, e.g. substring matching.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. If you come up this question all by yourself, I would call you a philosophical genius.

A word is not a single entity. It is a universal, or a class of entities that have a common property. Every time you write down "x", you only write down an instance of x.

Humans have the ability to sense universals or the common property of different things. Take the colour red for example, you have seen many red things, but no one ever saw red alone without shape, area, depth, etc. You know what the colour red looks like because you have the ability to sense universals.

Similar remarks apply to words spoken, heard or read.

Source: Russell, Bertrand [An Inquiry into Meaning and Truth](https://archive.org/stream/BertrandRussell-AnInquaryIntoMeaningAndTruth/AnInquiryIntoMeaningAndTruth#page/n5/mode/2up)

Comment: I did come up with this question myself. I dislike philosophy because there is no solid answer, just speculations.

Comment: @Amad27 - keep asking, my friend. Answers are not as important as questions, IMHO.

Comment: the problem is, if I keep asking then what should I do without an answer? Like this for example. I know I am supposed to interpret this way, but I dont know **why**, which is why I want to avoid philosophy as much as possbible. Should I just interpret the way I did **without a reason?**

Comment: @Amad27 - That's another good question. In the realm of philosophy, people generally disagree with each other, but often times good questions heralds good answers. Be warned, philosophical capacity stays with a person for only a very brief period. If you are at your philosophical peek and if you have a natural tendency to ask questions like this, please don't hesitate to ask. The above answer is based on facts. Then you'll ask by what we know facts, etc, etc. If you keep asking questions like this, some day we will get to the bottom of things.

Comment: but I have the major question: Should I just interpret the way I did without a reason? Like before I never thought about letters looking the _same_ I just took the identical things to have the same meaning. **there was no specific reason**, what should I do? Continue the way I did before? **Without reason?** Did you also do it **without reason?**

Comment: The reasons given above is based on observed facts. There is virtually no speculation in this case.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It was helpful, can I ask one more thing? So we take similar things to have the same meaning because otherwise. It would be impossible to do anything? So you make assumptions otherwise or is impossible to do anything?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "things." If you mean verbal utterances, similarity alone is not enough. We also need to take account of intention. That is why we can understand heavy accent. The necessary degree of similarly cannot be precisely decided.

Comment: what do you mean by "intention?"

Comment: The word the speaker intended to say. If we hear a German say "De doc vaks hiss tail," we know he uttered an instance of "dog." But if an Englishman makes the same noise, we may think he uttered an instance of "dock."

Comment: so what is the ultimatum?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe I'm years behind you.

Comment: thank you for all you have done. I just asked for an ultimatum of the question that : "should we take what is written as the closest identifiable thing from experience?" Such as like an "x" having the same meaning as "2x"?? THANKS!!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but chapter 1, page 25 probably will answer your question. It says similarity to a standard is essential, but not sufficient. We need also to know the speaker or writer's intentions.

Comment: @Amad27 - I don't understand your last question, but I don't blame you. It happens so often that people have a genuine question but don't have the words  to express the question; but as soon as one gains verbal skills, he loses the ability to contemplate those things. That is why philosophical capacity is very rare.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The Question: We interpret similar things to mean the same thing, and this **can** be wrong, but this is the **best bet** right?

Comment: Similarity plus intentions. Yes, this can be wrong. As a rule, philosophical scrutiny only increases doubt.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The thing that there are no rules is why I dislike philosophy to the greatest point.